# Add Multiple OneSignal APP in Custom Notification in laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications, onesignal, web-push

I have two Notification channels

`app/Channels/Reseller/Web/OneSignalWeb.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Channels\Reseller\Web;

use Berkayk\OneSignal\OneSignalClient;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\Exceptions\CouldNotSendNotification;
use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\OneSignalChannel;

class OneSignalWeb extends OneSignalChannel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $client = new OneSignalClient(
            env("ONESIGNAL_RESELLER_APP_ID"),
            env("ONESIGNAL_RESELLER_REST_API_KEY"),
            ''
        );
        parent::__construct($client);
    }

    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     * @param \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification $notification
     *
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \NotificationChannels\OneSignal\Exceptions\CouldNotSendNotification
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        if (!$userIds = $notifiable->devices()->where('platform', 'web')->pluck('uuid')->toArray()) {
            return;
        }
        /** @var ResponseInterface $response */
        $response = $this->oneSignal->sendNotificationCustom(
            $this->payload($notifiable, $notification, $userIds)
        );

        if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
            throw CouldNotSendNotification::serviceRespondedWithAnError($response);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

`app/Channels/Merchant/Web/OneSignalWeb.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Channels\Merchant\Web;

use Berkayk\OneSignal\OneSignalClient;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\Exceptions\CouldNotSendNotification;
use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\OneSignalChannel;

class OneSignalWeb extends OneSignalChannel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $client = new OneSignalClient(
            env("ONESIGNAL_MERCHANT_APP_ID"),
            env("ONESIGNAL_MERCHANT_REST_API_KEY"),
            ''
        );
        parent::__construct($client);
    }

    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     * @param \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification $notification
     *
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \NotificationChannels\OneSignal\Exceptions\CouldNotSendNotification
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        if (!$userIds = $notifiable->devices()->where('platform', 'web')->pluck('uuid')->toArray()) {
            return;
        }
        /** @var ResponseInterface $response */
        $response = $this->oneSignal->sendNotificationCustom(
            $this->payload($notifiable, $notification, $userIds)
        );

        if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
            throw CouldNotSendNotification::serviceRespondedWithAnError($response);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

In both of these channel only the difference is that in `__construct`we load different keys for both `Reseller` and `Merchant`

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $client = new OneSignalClient(
            env("ONESIGNAL_RESELLER_APP_ID"),
            env("ONESIGNAL_RESELLER_REST_API_KEY"),
            ''
        );
        parent::__construct($client);
    }
```

And this is the Nofications/Base.php where i've load both `ResellerWeb` and `MerchantWeb` Notification in `via` methods

```
public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'database',
            'broadcast',
            ResellerWeb::class,
            MerchantWeb::class,
        ];
    }
```

I want to optimize the norification where instead of loading `MerchantWeb::class` and `ResellerWeb::cass` i want to create and load a general channel lets say `NotificationWeb::class` and want to use it for both `Reseller` and `Merchant`. And when i use it i will need to switch the `env()` keys based on for which i use.

How can this be achieved

Comment: Please don't add your code as images :-) . [Here is several good reasons why you shouldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1766219). And if you're wondering how you should add your code, then you can read that here: [How do I format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/1766219).

Comment: And I'm afraid that I don't understand the question. So maybe rephrase it or add some more details - in case others find themselves in my shoes. :-)

Comment: @Zeth Hi Thanks for sharing it i have updated my post with codes and detail explanation. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Perfect rephrase and refactor! :-) Now I think I get it. I'm unsure if I have a good answer, though. :-/ ... Have you considered, making the `ResellerWeb`- and `MerchantWeb`-classes extend a parent class?

Comment: ``ResellerWeb`` and ``MerchantWeb`` already extends class from ``OneSignalChannel``